# Tomcat cannot access files created by java API

Tags: java, tomcat, runtime.exec

In process of creating a java based web application I have encountered this problem:

creating a new directory:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir /home/me/web/export"));
```

copying image:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp /home/me/images/a.jpg /home/me/web/export"
```

next I will create a download link to "a.jpg" in my JSP file. Until now everything works fine but when i deploy my webaplication on tomcat and try to download the file i get this message:

```
Http Status 404 - The requested resource (/export/a.jpg) is not available.
```

I have checked the directory and the image is available there. One thing worth mentioning is that after I rename the image to for example 'b.jpg' and again rename it back to 'a.jpg', the link will work just fine.

**Edit 1**
This problem affects the files created by JAVA API as well. I used a Filewriter to create 'data.xml' in the same directory and I got the same page as before when I tried to access it through a link in JSP page.

I desperately tried to solve this problem by giving all available permissions to everyone 'chmod 777 file' without any success.

**Edit 2**
I realized that after stopping the tomcat and restarting it everything goes back to normal and links are working fine now. I assume that tomcat somehow holds this newly created file so, all this said is there anything I can do to solve this?

**Final Edit:**
This happens to be more of a server problem so it is logical to move it to ServerFault.
Thanks everyone for their responses.

Comment: Why you are using system calls for something that could be easily done with Java API (creating directories, coping files)?

Comment: @mdoust can be a matter of security, your Tomcat server way not have permissions to this file. Try altering the folder attributes or putting the file in other location (not c dir)

Comment: @Crozin Thanks for your response, Creating a new Directory using JAVA API is quite easy but I couldn't find any straightforward way to handle copying the image. All possible solutions i find involves using input Streams and output streams. Is there any other way to go around it?

Comment: @MichaelA I checked the permission with 'ls -l' command before and after renaming the image and both are the same:  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 moh moh 20165 2012-12-10 13:07 logo.png

Comment: You could use `Files.copy(String source, String target)` if you're using Java7, or `FileUtils.copy(File source, File target)` from Apache Commons IO for Java5/6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem yesterday when working on another J2EE project. To my surprise the problem roots from the IDE itself. I used Netbeans IDE for the project and saved images uploaded by clients to **'/web/export/'** inside project directory.

What I didn't realize then was that Netbeans deploy the files from **'/build/web'** to tomcat and not the **'/web'** and images that are placed in '/web/export' in run-time do not necessarily get propagated to build directory asynchronously. Restarting the server initiated a build process,  propagating all changes to build directory and solving the given problem.

I guess if I deployed the war file manually to the tomcat server, I would have not faced these problems in the first place.